# Variables in property files in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Can I use a propertie inside a application.properties?

sample:

```
myLevel=ERROR

logging.level.org.springframework=$myLevel
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=$myLevel
```

tks

Comment: @XtremeBiker apparently you can if you use `${variable}`. Out of curiosity using spring-boot `1.5.4.RELEASE` I defined `loglevel=DEBUG` at the beginning of the file and then `logging.level.root=${loglevel}`, and it worked without a sweat. Even IntelliJ recognized it and provided it as a suggestion...weird... What am I missing / overlooking?

Comment: @Morfic, yeah, it seems to be a feature I haven't noticed about or recently introduced.. Have found it in the docs an going to provide an answer.

Comment: @XtremeBiker yep, that's what I was missing. I looked over that page yesterday night but somehow skipped that section... long day. I even searched for [issues/features](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1672) that allowed SpEL because I was under the impression that it's not supported, which it isn't, but placeholders seem to be now, so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might use property placeholders:

> The values in application.properties are filtered through the existing Environment when they are used so you can refer back to previously defined values (e.g. from System properties).

For your case:

```
myLevel=ERROR

logging.level.org.springframework=${myLevel}
logging.level.org.apache.catalina=${myLevel}
```

**See also:**

- [Spring Boot - Placeholders in properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties)